# Pointless SQL vs PHP if

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I need to manipulate entries in a mySQL table using code like this

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
 $sql = "UPDATE `siteims` SET refs = refs + 1 WHERE imid = '{$item->img}';";
 $sql .= "UPDATE `lists` SET refs = refs + 1 WHERE lid = '{$item->lili}'";
 $dbh->exec($sql);
}
```

There may be as many as 50 items in $items.  A variation on this code would be

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
 if ('z' != $img->img)
 $sql = "UPDATE `siteims` SET refs = refs + 1 WHERE imid = '{$item->img}';";
 if ('z' != $item->lili)
 $sql .= "UPDATE `lists` SET refs = refs + 1 WHERE lid = '{$item->lili}'";
 $dbh->exec($sql);
}
```

In both cases I am executing a sequence of SQL statements for EACH item in $items.  My questions

1. Would it not be a whole lot more efficient to build $sql for **items** and then execute it?
2. But then if all of the, potentially, 50 items in $items produces meaningful SQL would that not mean a very slowly executing batch of SQL statements?
3. Finally, is it better to perform PHP side **if** tests as in the second version of my code or just build the SQL and let mySQL deal with the fact that the WHERE test returns an empty row?

I'd much appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Surely you can construct tests to answer these questions? It seems that the answer to your question lies with another question: where is your bottleneck?

Comment: `'z' != strlen($img->img)` - what's that? o_O

Comment: Well spotted - there should have been no strlen there.  I was thinking of putting in another version of the code as I put in this one

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `in` clause, instead, e.g.

```
$sql = "UPDATE .... WHERE imid IN (" . implode($array_that_has_the_ids) . ")"
```

and reduce yourself down to just one single SQL query. However, this can fail if you're trying to use a HUGE aray - the generated query could exceed the max_allowed_packet setting and get killed.

As for your strlen... what's the point of comparing strlen results against `'z'`? strlen returns an integer, you might as well be doing `if (apple == orange)` instead.

Comment: The strlen bit was a red-herring.  I was thinking of another version of the code as I typed it all in.

Answer (score 1):

At first place I advice you to use IN clause and just 2 separated queries...
You may have to escape those 2 elements $item->img and $item->lili ..

```
$ids = array("siteims"=>array(), "lists"=>array());
foreach($items as $item)
{
    $ids['siteims'][] = "'" . $item->img . "'";
    $ids['lists'][] = "'" . $item->lili . "'" ;
}
if(!empty($ids['siteims'])){
    $sql = "UPDATE `siteims` SET refs = refs + 1 WHERE imid IN (".implode(',', $ids["siteims"]).")";
    $dbh->exec($sql);
}

if(!empty($ids['lists'])){
    $sql = "UPDATE `lists` SET refs = refs + 1 WHERE lid IN (".implode(',', $ids["lists"]).")";
    $dbh->exec($sql);
}
```

Comment: I am "unaccepting" this answer for a reason.  The issue is this - the IN clause cannot handle adjusting the refs column correctly if there are repeated entries.  e.g. if my array ends up containing ('idA','idB','idA','idC') the refs column for the row bearing idA will b e adjusted only once - not the desired result.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that.  Thank you for the answer anyway.  I have voted it up.